# WSL Ubuntu. How to remove a file with 0 hardlinks?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, inode

I somehow managed to end up with the following:
`ls -la`:

```
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 umain umain 4096 Jan 30 12:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 umain umain 4096 Jan 30 10:57 ..
-rw-r--r-- 0 umain umain    0 Jan 30 12:32 something.php
drwxrwxrwx 1 umain umain 4096 Jan 30 10:59 src
```

Note that the hardlink count is `0` for `something.php`.

Likewise, `stat something.php`:

```
 File: something.php
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 2h/2d   Inode: 2814749767170024  Links: 0
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   umain)   Gid: ( 1000/   umain)
Access: 2023-01-30 12:32:19.055876000 -0500
Modify: 2023-01-30 12:32:19.055876000 -0500
Change: 2023-01-30 12:32:19.055876000 -0500
 Birth: -
```

No matter what I try, I can't delete this. `sudo rm -f` tells me I don't have the permissions. `sudo su | rm -f` also doesn't work. I tried to 777 it before removing it. No luck.

I can edit the file just fine, cat it, etc. etc. Just can't remove it.

Is there a way to remove the inode completely

This is in Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL windows 10.

Comment: What filesystem is the file on?

Comment: Try running `ls -laZ something.php` to see if somehow SE Linux is involved here. I doubt it, but on “real” Linux systems SE Linux causes nonsense like this. Also I check the status of SE Linux via `sestatus` to see if SE Linux is actually enforcing anything. But who knows if this matters with WSL so hey… This is a comment based on some kinda experience!

Comment: @user1686 should be ext4 (from fstab and fsck). `df -Th` comes up as `lxfs`

Comment: @Giacomo1968 That's just giving me -rwxrwxrwx 0 umain umain ? 10 Jan 30 13:21 something.php. Doesn't look like much here

Comment: @D.Mill Correct. Seems like the issue is with WSL in some way. Hope you can find a solution!

Comment: Possibly the file was already deleted but is still accessed by a process. Use `lsof` to check if the file is in use: `lsof | grep something.php`. If this is the case, it will be gone after a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue on a CentOS machine.

The comment by @harrymc solved it, an old process was using that file.

1. `lsof | grep <filename>` to find the process
2. `kill <ps ID>`  to kill the process, the file then vanished

---

> Possibly the file was already deleted but is still accessed by a process. Use `lsof` to check if the file is in use: *lsof | grep something.php`. If this is the case, it will be gone after a reboot. –
> harrymc
> Jan 30, 2023 at 21:01